# C# public list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, list, static, instance

I'm converting from VB to C# and struggling to workout how to access a public list of objects...

```
class Program
{
    public List<players> myListOfPlayers = new List<players>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        foreach(var player in myListOfPlayers)
        {

        }
    } 

    class players
    {
        public string playerName { get; set; }
        public string playerCountry { get; set; }

    }
}
```

In my Main module I can't access "myListOfPlayers".

Comment: You have to make an instance of the Program class, Main() is static. Or make the list static too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an instance of your `Program` class:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program(); // p is the instance.

        foreach(var player in p.myListOfPlayers)
        {

        }
    }
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
Dim p As New Program
```

Alternatively you could make `myListOfPlayers` static.

As an additional comment, you should try and follow proper naming conventions, for example: `C#` classes should have their first letter capitalized.  `players` should be `Players`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure you don't need to do this within a class in VB.

Comment: the question is tagged c# not vb.net

Comment: @K.B - Yes, hence my `C#` answer. I included the `VB.NET` snippet to show the OP how to achieve a new instance of an object in `C#`.

Comment: Cheers Darren! Very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

By design you cannot access a non  static member  from  a static member

From  MSDN 
*`Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method parameter.`*

You  need  static  modifier here

```
public static List<players> myListOfPlayers = new List<players>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a non-static context from a static context. So try to access the list within your constructor.

```
class Program
{
    public List<players> myListOfPlayers = new List<players>();

    public Program(){
      foreach(var player in myListOfPlayers)
      {

      }
    } 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Program();

} 

    class players
    {
        public string playerName { get; set; }
        public string playerCountry { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `myListOfPlayer` is not static so it only exists within the context of an instance of the class. Since the main method is static, it does not exist in the context of an instance, and so it cannot "see" instance members

You need to make you `myListOfPlayer` static so that you can access it from a instance method.

```
public static List<players> myListOfPlayers = new List<players>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<players> myListOfPlayers = new List<players>();

        foreach (var player in myListOfPlayers)
        {

        }
    }


}
class players
{
    public string playerName { get; set; }
    public string playerCountry { get; set; }

}
```

try the above code, it should work.
let me know if you any question